# Not able to show mongo collection using React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, collections

I am trying to list out my projects collection using react and Meteor.
I have two collections Resolutions and Projects.
I am able to get the Resolution collection to display on frontend but i am unsuccessful in displaying the Projects collection on the frontend. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

The error I get in the console is:

```
 Projects.find() is not a function
```

I also get this error in the console as well:

```
warning.js:44 Warning: There is an internal error in the React performance measurement code. Did not expect componentDidMount timer to start while render timer is still in progress for another instance.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i am stuck on this problem, thank you.

Here is my Projects.jsx file that is listed under the folder pages:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';
import ReacCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

import ProjectsForm from '../projects/ProjectsForm.jsx';
import ProjectSingle from '../projects/ProjectSingle.jsx';

if(Meteor.isClient){
    Projects = new Mongo.Collection('projects');
}

export default class Projects extends TrackerReact(Component) {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            subscription: {
                projects: Meteor.subscribe('allProjects')
            }
        }
    }
    ComponentWillUnmount() {
        this.state.subscription.projects.stop();
    }
    projects() {
        return Projects.find().fetch();
    }
    render() {
        DocHead.setTitle('Projects | My Projects');
        return (
            <ReacCSSTransitionGroup
                component="div"
                transitionName="route"
                transitionEnterTimeout={600}
                transitionAppearTimeout={600}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={400}
                transitionAppear={true}>
                <h1>Projects</h1>
                <ProjectsForm />
                {this.projects().map((project) => {
                    return <ProjectSingle key={project._id} project={project} />
                })}
            </ReacCSSTransitionGroup>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the ProjectSingle.jsx file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class ProjectSingle extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <li>
                <a href={`projects/${this.props.project._id}`}>{this.props.project.text}</a>
            </li>
        )
    }
}
```

In my server folder i have a file called publish.js that holds my collections:

```
Projects = new Mongo.Collection('projects');
Meteor.publish('allProjects', function(){
    return Projects.find();
});

Meteor.publish('project', function(){
    return Projects.find({project: this.id});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to change the name of my Projects.jsx file to ProjectsWrapper.jsx as the name space Projects was already being used by the Collection. I could of done the opposite and changed the Collection name but i figured this was the best way for what i have.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not properly referencing your `Projects` collection. Instead of defining your `Projects` collection in 2 places, define it once in a location that can be referenced from both the client and server, then import it as needed. For example:

1) Create a new folder/file to hold your `Projects` collection (following the [Meteor Guide's](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#example-app-structure) application structure):

**/imports/api/projects/collection.js**

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
const Projects = new Mongo.Collection('projects');
export default Projects;
```

2) Modify your client side `Projects.jsx` file to change around your `Projects` references:

**replace the following**

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
  Projects = new Mongo.Collection('projects');
}
```

**with the following**

```
import Projects from '/imports/api/projects/collection';
```

3) Modify your server side `publish.js` file as follows:

**replace the following**

```
Projects = new Mongo.Collection('projects');
```

**with the following**

```
import Projects from '/imports/api/projects/collection';
```